# Lucida Console font

Tags: fonts, lucida

How can I use the Lucida Console font? I would like that it only affects one word of a paragraph. Is it possible to use it if I am writing my document in Overleaf?

Comment: Lucida Console is not a free font, so I don't think Overleaf offers it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Does`\usepackage{lucidabr}`  work?.

Comment: Is there any other font similar to it?

Comment: Lucida Console is not [in this list](https://www.overleaf.com/help/193-what-otf-slash-ttf-fonts-are-supported-via-fontspec) of supported fonts.

Answer (score 1):

In my windows this here works fine with xelatex or lualatex. But I doubt that the font is in overleaf.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
{\fontspec{Lucida Console} Lucida Console} abc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it is not available, but thanks anyway.